# understanding assembly and stack %ebp above vs below

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack

if my assembly code ...

```
   0x08048cc4 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x08048cc5 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048cc7 <+3>:     push   %esi
   0x08048cc8 <+4>:     push   %ebx
   0x08048cc9 <+5>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048ccc <+8>:     lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax    // input 3
   0x08048ccf <+11>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048cd3 <+15>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax     // input 2
   0x08048cd6 <+18>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048cda <+22>:    movl   $0x804a1aa,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048ce2 <+30>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax      // input 1
   0x08048ce5 <+33>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048ce8 <+36>:    call   0x804870c <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
```

Is there a way to print value of input 1,2,3 if I set the break point at <+36>  ?

I know I can keep break at <+8> and do some (gdb) i r to get %eax each time. but is there a better way to do this at one break point at <+36>

my input is 14, 115   ( input 2, input 3 ) 
input 1 is format ( "%d, %d")

I have tried to do something like, but haven't quite understand what I am reading ..

```
(gdb) x /20wx $esp
0xbffff070: 0x0804b820  0x0804a1aa  0xbffff08c  0xbffff088
0xbffff080: 0x00000001  0x7a000002  0x00000073  0x0000000e
0xbffff090: 0xbffff168  0xbffff164  0xbffff0c8  0x08048a4d
0xbffff0a0: 0x0804b820  0x08049f2c  0x00000000  0xb7e5164d
0xbffff0b0: 0xb7fc93c4  0xb7fff000  0xb7fc9000  0x00000000

(gdb) x /20wx $ebp
0xbffff098: 0xbffff0c8  0x08048a4d  0x0804b820  0x08049f2c
0xbffff0a8: 0x00000000  0xb7e5164d  0xb7fc93c4  0xb7fff000
0xbffff0b8: 0xb7fc9000  0x00000000  0x08049e60  0x00000000
0xbffff0c8: 0x00000000  0xb7e37a83  0x00000002  0xbffff164
0xbffff0d8: 0xbffff170  0xb7feccea  0x00000002  0xbffff164

(gdb) x /20wd $ebp
0xbffff098: -1073745720 134515277   134527008   134520620
0xbffff0a8: 0   -1209723315 -1208183868 -1207963648
0xbffff0b8: -1208184832 0   134520416   0
0xbffff0c8: 0   -1209828733 2   -1073745564
0xbffff0d8: -1073745552 -1208038166 2   -1073745564
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At +36 `sscanf` has not yet been invoked, so you'd only see random memory garbage for the two output variables that you call `input2/3`.

`Input1` is not the format, it is the string to be parsed.

What that call looks like is: `sscanf(input1, "%d %d", &input2, &input3)`

You can of course examine the variables, using `x/s $eax` for `input1` and `x/d` for the `input2/3`:

```
(gdb) x/s $eax
0xffffdba6:     "14 115"
(gdb) ni
(gdb) x/d $ebp-0xc
0xffffd97c:     14
(gdb) x/d $ebp-0x10
0xffffd978:     115
```

(Note I have printed `input1` before the `sscanf`, but the others after.)
See the gdb help for format specifiers.